# Why do we need json.parse and json.stringify while dealing with localStorage object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why do we need json.parse and json.stringify while dealing with localStorage object?
What if we do not use JSON.parse and JSON.stringify(value) in below code?

In Get method  why can not we say `localStorage.getItem(key) as T;`

```
export class StorageService 
{
    constructor() { }

    public Get<T>(key: string): T
    {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) as T;
    }

    public Set(key: string, value: any): void
    {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }

    public Clear()
    {
        localStorage.clear();
    }

    public Remove(key: string)
    {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because local storage elements are serialized

Comment: Did you try it?